# Unnest matrix in base R

Tags: r, matrix, nested, base-r

Consider a nested matrix of this form, of which each element is a vector, list, or dataframe:

```r
m <- matrix(replicate(3, list(1:3)))
m
#     [,1]     
#[1,] integer,3
#[2,] integer,3
#[3,] integer,3
```

How does one "unnest" this matrix? i.e. get this output:

```r
unnestFunction(m)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `c`:

```r
c(m)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

The "just use `c()`" is one way. You can also remove the dimensions attribute:

```
dim(m) <- NULL

str(m)
#------------
List of 3
 $ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
 $ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
 $ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```r
m[T]

#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

---

Another possible solution:

```r
lapply(m, identity)

#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
> m[,1]
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Try `c`

```
m <- matrix(replicate(3, list(1:3)))
c(m)
```

giving

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

**2)** Mucking with internal representations probably isn't a good idea but this does work as well:

```
structure(m, .Dim = NULL)
```